# undefiined useContext destructure

Tags: reactjs, react-context, use-context

i am trying save user object in context but i am gettin g undefined
this is my context:

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const UserContext = createContext(null)
```

this is routs :

```
import { UserContext } from './contexts/UserContext.js';



  const [user, setUser] = useState();




<UserContext.Provider value={{user:user , setUser:setUser}}>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" exact element={ <Login />} />
        <Route path="/numberinput" exact element={<NumberInput />} />
        <Route path="/VerifyPhone" exact element={<VerifyPhone />} />
        <Route path="/Register" exact element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/ChangePassword" exact element={<ChangePassword />} />

        <Route path="/" exact element={<PrivateRoute><Home /></PrivateRoute>} />
        {/* <Route path="/Answers" exact element={<Answers />} />
        <Route path="/results/:id/:quizzes_id" exact element={<Results />} /> */}
        <Route path="/payment" element={<PrivateRoute><Payment /></PrivateRoute>} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<FourOFour />} />
      </Routes>
    </UserContext.Provider>
```

and this is how i want to store data in another file:

```
import { UserContext } from '../../contexts/UserContext.js';


  const { setUser } = useContext(UserContext);



 baseUrl
        .post('api/v1/login', data)
        .then((response) => {
          setUser(response.data.data);
          console.log(response.data.data);
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: response.data.data.message,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1000,
          }).then(() => {
            
            window.location.pathname = '/';
          });
        })
```

and when i log the user in '/' rout i am getting undefiend

Comment: Are you getting a log from **console.log(response.data.data)** ?

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize properties of the context in first parameter of the createContext function as follows,

```js
    const userContext = createContext({ user: null, setUser: () => {} })
```

Comment: its not undefined now it is null 
the setUser doesn't work i think

Comment: That's because you're logging it olnly on component mount. You need an useEffect hook to look for changes in user state.

Comment: but when i change the user to a static string value it logs the string

Comment: Then either you're not getting data from API. Or maybe you're not setting it correctly. Try to check the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: i am getting user from api corrctly i checked it

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add an initial value to the `useState` hook.

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
```

And,

Don't use only a **console.log()** to log the user as it runs only once when your App mounts.

Do this instead to log the user every time it changes:

```
// state
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

// log user every time it changes
useEffect(()=> {
    console.log(user, "user from effect hook")
}, [user])
```

Set user in **Login** component

```
import React from "react";
// import UserContext correctly
import { UserContext } from "<path-to-UserContext>";

export default function Login() {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext);
  // set the user
  useEffect(() => {
    setUser("something");
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
```

Note: I'm assuming that you are getting the data from API correctly.

Comment: yes i am getting data from api and its correct 
i log the user in useEffect but still it is null
i think setUser doesn't work

Comment: @saeed It should be null for the first time. When setUser is invoked, you should get another log with the updated value of user.

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
    setUser({...user , log:'ll'})
    console.log(user);
  },[user])


i did this but still there is no user

Comment: @saeed Don't **setUser** in a useEffect call where **user** itself is a dependecy. This results in too many re-renders. Just log the user in useEffect. Use another useEffect in App.js or any other child component to set the user.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer. I hope you can troubleshoot it now. Or, you need to add complete code for **App** and **Login** components (don't make it too long) along with directory structure.

Comment: i don't get it 
the useEffect after some rerender should  show the user 
i set the user in a login page and in dashboard in useEffect i logged it

Comment: sorry i mean home component

Comment: thank you @Amit the updated answer doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244734/discussion-between-amit-and-saeed).

Comment: window.location.pathname = '/';

this was the problem
changed it to navigate and problem solved